# Dataannotations localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localization, data-annotations

**model**

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetaData))]
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class UserMetaData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelValidation), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequired")]
    [LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute("UserName", NameResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelValidation))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

**view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Gönder" />
    </div>
}
```

**LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute**

```
public class LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    private PropertyInfo _nameProperty;
    private Type _resourceType;

    public LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute(string displayNameKey)
        : base(displayNameKey)
    { }

    public Type NameResourceType
    {
        get { return _resourceType; }
        set
        {
            _resourceType = value;
            //initialize nameProperty when type property is provided by setter  
            _nameProperty = _resourceType.GetProperty(base.DisplayName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        }
    }
    public override string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {              
            //check if nameProperty is null and return original display name value  
            if (_nameProperty == null) { return base.DisplayName; }
            return (string)_nameProperty.GetValue(_nameProperty.DeclaringType, null);
        }
    }
}
```

**resource file**

[image]

**output**

[image]

RequiredAttribute localization works, but LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute does not work. I cant find any solution to fix this.

Any suggestion, where is the missing?

Comment: I dont got this! Why are you extending DysplayNameAttr? This control supports Localization as the Requerid!

Comment: @Fals, I dont understand. Could you explain it? DisplayAttribute does not support localization

Comment: Yep it does, Name is the resourceName when you provide the ResourceType propertie!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You seem to be reinventing the wheels with this `LocalizedDisplayNameAttribute` attribute. This functionality is already built into the framework, right into the `[Display]` attribute that you could use directly:

```
public class UserMetaData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelValidation), ErrorMessageResourceName = nameof(Resources.ModelValidation.UserNameRequired)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.ModelValidation), Name = nameof(Resources.ModelValidation.UserName))]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

As far as why your wheel reinvention doesn't work, well, can't say for sure. Why care when you could get rid of it anyways.

Comment: Error:`Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'Resources.ModelValidation' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'UserName'.`

Comment: Your resource is setted as Internal, so its fails! Check the print screen!

Comment: @Fals, I know this, but I cant change it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't know what is this `Resources.ModelValidation`. You should put the type over there that was generated for you. So for example if you put a `Resources.resx` file in the root of your web application and set the `Custom Tool` to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` and define a `UserName` key inside this resource file then your attribute should look like this: `[Display(Name = "UserName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources))]`. The important part here is to set the Custom Tool for this resource file to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator` so that the designer generates public properties, not internal.

Comment: The problem is the Access Modifier @DarinDimitrov! He must use Internal!

Comment: No, he should not use internal. If he uses internal and this resource is in a separate class library, you will never be able to retrieve the value inside a Razor view, which as you know, is generated in a different assembly by ASP.NET at runtime.

Comment: ModelValidation is my resourse file name (ModelValidation.resx) that is under, Root/App_GlobalResources/ folder

Comment: Thats what I said above @DarinDimitrov! But he said that needs it Internal! Makes no sense!

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi, put this resource file in the root of your application, for example in `~/ModelValidation.resx` and then set the Custom Tool to `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. IIRC there was a bug with the `App_GlobalResources` special folder. Let me try to find some info about it. I remember having an issue with it.

Comment: Alright found it. Read this answer of mine:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14761762/29407 If you want to keep your resource file in the `App_GlobalResources` you're gonna have to set it as embedded resource. And yeah, you should use `typeof(Resources.ModelValidation)` in this case.

Comment: `App_GlobalResources.ModelValidation` and your last comment. Now it is working, Thanks...