# How can I change @Html.DisplayFor item name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nume, "Name")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.adresa, "Adresă")
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email, "Email")
    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modeItem => item.localitati.localitate, "Localitate")
    </td>
```

This does not work, the column names are not changing. Instead the database table column names are displayed.

How can I change column names? (e.g "nume" into "Name" or "adresa" into "Adresa"). Thanks.

Comment: It's doesn't appear your code is showing where the column names are displayed, but the column (cell) values in the rows.  What does the code look like where you are trying to display the name?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), In your model you can use [Display Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify a display name for your property

Like this:

```
[Display(Name = "Email")
public string email { get; set; }
```

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16837855/dataannotations-localization) also addresses localization.

Comment: Still it doesn't work.
I've put the code in Models/Validation Class:
[Required(ErrorMessage = "...")]
[StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "...")] 
[Display(Name = "Nume")]
public string nume {get; set;}

Comment: Is there another way to do this besides annotation as annotation is a bad idea when your model is autogenerated?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for column headers like "Name" column because DisplayFor will show the value of item.nume?  It seems you are passing in template names in DisplayFor's second parameter.

Also, shouldn't modelItem and item be the same variable name?

Comment: Yes, I am asking for column headers like "Name" column. And yes, DisplayFor shows the value of item.nume . And I've passed the names in DisplyFor because it works for "@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nume, "Nume")" and I tought it will also work for DisplayFor's. 

"modelItem" is a variable so why should it be the same name as item? (well MVC4 is new to me). Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: No, `modelItem` should not be the same as `item`.

Comment: But richinator38 is correct. You are using the overload that passes a template name: [DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407420(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: I'm not using that anymore, i thought it will work as for "@Html.LabelFor(model => model.nume, "Nume")". Does this work "[Display(Name = "Nume")] public string nume {get; set;}" if I put it in Models, validation class?

Comment: The way I have done it is by having a row for the header of the grid:  '<tr><th>@LabelConstants.Nume</th></tr>'.  That LabelConstants is shared in the model '[Display(Name=LabelConstants.Nume)]'.

Comment: Instead of using @LabelConstants.Nume, use @Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.nume).  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833697(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: I am already using that. "@Html.DisplayNameFor(item => item.nume)" displays on page "nume" (where nume = table column name from DB). **How can I display "Name"?**  (change "nume" in "Name" without modify the table column name from DB)